# How to limit an array size in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, limit

is there a way I can limit the number of elements that can be added to a MongoDB Array? I have a `Tables` collection with an `Attendees` array that should only contain 10 elements seats).

Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#up._S_slice) as a modifier to `$push` when you update the document:

```
$push: { "field": { $each: ["val1", "val2"], $slice: -10 }}
```

This will cause `field` to only consist of the last 10 elements (giving you a "rolling window" of values pushed into the field).

Comment: For the full query:

`db.getCollection('col').updateOne({}, {$push: {"field": {$each: ["val1"], $slice: -10}}})`