# Updating a value that is dependent on a newly updated document key

Tags: mongodb

My goal is to add a comment to my CommentFeed and while doing that I want to push that comment into my `topComments` field and also update the 'numOfComments' . I want to limit the `topComments` to only 3 comments (How would I even set that up?). And how do I take the previous value of `numOfComments` and add one to it?

```
 CommentFeed.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: commentId },
            {
                $push: {
                    comments: {
                        text: req.body.text
                    },
                 $push: topComments:{text: req.body.text}, <--- Limit this somehow to only allow an array length of 3?
                 $set: numOfComments: ? ,  <---What kind of logic is used here?
                }
            },
            { new: true }
        )
```

**CommentFeed Schema**

```
    const CommentFeedSchema = new Schema({
              topComments:[{text:{type:String}}],
              numOfComments:{type:Number},
              comments: [
                   text: { type: String, required: true }
                    ]});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit an array size in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932723/how-to-limit-an-array-size-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue (limiting the `topComments` array size) you can use the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#up._S_slice) operator. This has already been answered in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932723/how-to-limit-an-array-size-in-mongodb). **But you might consider** computing `topComments` from `comments` using the`$slice` operator in the projection argument:

```
CommentFeed.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: -3 } } )
```

For the second issue (updating a document using existing fields from that document), it is not something you can do in a simple `findOneAndUpdate` call. This was also discussed in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3974985/3488179).
**But you might consider** computing `numOfComments` instead of updating it every time. You can do that with the `$size` operator of the aggregation framework:

```
CommentFeed.aggregate({$project: { numOfComments: { $size:"$comments" }}})
```